# h5ai folder date of modification is wrong

Tags: apache, apache2

---

**PROBLEM**

---

h5ai web server index for Apache Server shows 'last modified' wrong dates for each of my folders on my index list. Files created, removed or modified inside one of index folders do not update modification date of the folder itself. For example, my main index page contains this folder:

[image]

Last modification date is set to 2013-04-26 22:30. When I open this folder, these files are listed:

[image]

See that modification dates of each of my files inside parent folder conflict with modification date of parent folder itself?

---

**ATTEMPTS**

---

I've already searched on available documentation and on the Web, but with no success. Restarting Apache or re-installing h5ai doesn't give any result.

---

**INFO**

---

I'm using Apache 2.2.22 and h5ai 0.22.1 .

Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found that h5ai has nothing to do with this problem. On Linux systems, files modified inside folders **do not** change modification date of parent folders. And this newbie fact I wasn't aware of. So, to solve this lack of date update, a simple call to **touch *YOUR-DIRECTORY-HERE*** would solve this. Touch Tool updates the modification date of files or directories to the present date and time.